# MAX and MIN on string array in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have started to learn Linq recently. I came across a few inbuild methods like Min() and Max().
The working of these two methods is fine with int[]. But when it comes to string[], I am curious how it will work. I have tried some codes

```
 string[] cars = { "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda" };
            Console.WriteLine(cars.Max());
            Console.WriteLine(cars.Min());
```

The output was like this:

**Volvo for Max()

BMW for Min()**

Can you please explain how it is working, is it taking the first letter in alphabetical order or is there any mechanism it is using like based on ASCII values etc?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1675

Comment: The characters have a unicode/utf16 value

Comment: In most simple terms, if you sorted your list of car makes alphabetically, the Min would be the first and the Max would be the last

Answer (score 3):

All types that implement the [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-6.0) or [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-6.0) interface can be compared, using the [CompareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=net-6.0) method implemented by each type.  All primitive types implement `IComparable<T>`, including `char` and `string`. LINQ's `Min(IEnumerable)` and `Max(IEnumerable)` use this implementation to find the minimum or maximum in an enumerable.

**String Comparisons**

Comparing strings though is a bit more interesting than comparing integers. The strings are typically compared in dictionary order (lexicographically) but ... whose dictionary? Different languages have different sorting rules, and sometimes two letters are considered a single one. Even Danes forget that `AA` is equivalent to `Å` in Danish.

The dictionary used to compare strings is provided by the [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0) class. By default, the current thread's culture is used which typically matches the culture of the end user (in desktop applications) or the system locale in server applications. In a Danish culture for example, `AA` is treated differently from `aa` - I think one of them is ordered after other letters of the same case and the other isn't, but don't ask me which.

The [InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0) specifies a locale-*in*sensitive culture that can be used to handle strings the same way in every locale. It uses mostly sensible settings (eg `.` for the decimal point) except dates, where it uses the US format instead of the ISO8601  (YYYY-MM-DD) format as everyone would expect.

**Custom comparisons**

It's possible to specify a different comparison method by passing a class that implements `IComparer` to any LINQ methods affected by order.  [Min(IEnumerable,IComparer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-min-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))) is one example.

The [StringComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=net-6.0) class contains some predefined comparers :

- [CurrentCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.currentculture?view=net-6.0) is the default
- [CurrentCultureIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase?view=net-6.0) uses the current culture but *ignores* case, so `A` is equal to `a`. This is very useful eg in dictionaries.
- [InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantculture?view=net-6.0) and `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` use the Invariant culture for ordering
- Finally, [Ordinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinal?view=net-6.0) and `OrdinalIgnoreCase` *don't* use a dictionary but compare the Unicode values of the characters. That's the fastest option if you don't care about locale rules

Answer (score 1):

With string list Min() or Max() follows the first and last word or letter respectively but in case of integers Min() or Max() follows the exact phenomena of finding the Minimum and Maximum numbers from the list.
[Please check this image and it's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovKxn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

`.Max()` use `Compare(String, String)`
which compares two specified String objects and returns an integer that indicates their relative position in the sort order.

Source code of `.Max()` for string compare

```
 public static TSource Max<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
            if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            Comparer<TSource> comparer = Comparer<TSource>.Default;
            TSource value = default(TSource);
            if (value == null) {
                foreach (TSource x in source) {
                    if (x != null && (value == null || comparer.Compare(x, value) > 0))
                        value = x;
                }
                return value;
            }
            else {
                bool hasValue = false;
                foreach (TSource x in source) {
                    if (hasValue) {
                        if (comparer.Compare(x, value) > 0) //Compare strings
                            value = x;
                    }
                    else {
                        value = x;
                        hasValue = true;
                    }
                }
                if (hasValue) return value;
                throw Error.NoElements();
            }
        }
```

Compare(String, String)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-6.0#system-string-compare(system-string-system-string)

Answer (score 1):

Strings are compared alphabetically, which translates into the following logic:

- which item has a higher first character
- which item has a higher second character
- which item has a higher third character
- ...

The difference is detected at the first character that differs. So, when you compare `string1` with `string2`, then `string1` is greater than `string2` if at their first differing character (from left to right), `string1` has a greater value at that position than `string2`. If `string2` is `string1` + `string3`, then the first difference between `string1` and `string2` is beyond the end of `string1` and at that point the comparison yields that `string2` is greater than `string1`.

If you are dissatisfied with this comparison, then you can specify what comparer you intend to use, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-max-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))

Basically in that case you need to implement an `IComparer` and pass it as a second parameter, like

```
cars.Max(c => c, yourcomparer)
```